# gensim Word2Vec - how to apply stochastic gradient descent?

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec, gradient-descent, stochastic

To my understanding, batch (vanilla) gradient descent makes one parameter update for all training data. Stochastic gradient descent (SGD) allows you to update parameter for each training sample, helping the model to converge faster, at the cost of high fluctuation in function loss.

[image]

Batch (vanilla) gradient descent sets `batch_size=corpus_size`.

SGD sets `batch_size=1`.

And mini-batch gradient descent sets `batch_size=k`, in which `k` is usually 32, 64, 128...

How does gensim apply SGD or mini-batch gradient descent? It seems that `batch_words` is the equivalent of `batch_size`, but I want to be sure.

Is setting `batch_words=1` in gensim model equivalent to applying SGD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `batch_words` in `gensim` refers to the size of work-chunks sent to worker threads.

The `gensim` `Word2Vec` class updates model parameters after each training micro-example of `(context)->(target-word)` (where `context` might be a single word, as in skip-gram, or the mean of several words, as in CBOW).

For example, you can review this optimized `w2v_fast_sentence_sg_neg()` cython function for skip-gram with negative-sampling, deep in the `Word2Vec` training loop:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/460dc1cb9921817f71b40b412e11a6d413926472/gensim/models/word2vec_inner.pyx#L159

Observe that it is considering exactly one target-word (`word_index` parameter) and one context-word (`word2_index`), and updating both the word-vectors (aka 'projection layer' `syn0`) and the model's hidden-to-output weights (`syn1neg`) before it might be called again with a subsequent single `(context)->(target-word)` pair.

Comment: ok, then my follow up question is, how do I apply SGD or mini-batch gradient of size `k` with gensim models?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `gensim` `Word2Vec` approach (closely modeled after the original Mikolov/Google `word2vec.c`) could be fairly described as SGD already. But, it doesn't have any configurably-sized mini-batch option: you'd have to write that yourself.